# CSS on Production is not same as local - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I'm working on Laravel project. I've deployed it on Linux server. There's a page that I'm using PDF. When I view the PDF file. It is showing different result between my local and production.

For example, when I'm using **text-decoration:underline**, it works properly on local but on the production, it will create line-through instead of underline. Furthermore, **line-height** command also display wrong result on production.

For the example code and the PDF's results,

```
<div style="text-decoration:underline;">
    Testing text.
</div>
```

This is my local's result,

[image]

And here is my production's result,

[image]

I really have no idea. to solve the issue. I hope someone could help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the actual CSS being used using your browsers "Developers Tools" (F12)

Comment: Which versions of PHP are you running on localhost vs on the server?